# How to sort tuples like this?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

`data = [ (2,2), (0,5), (8,0), (9,8), (7,14), (13,12), (14,13) ]`

I want this tuple list to be sorted like this:

`data = [ (14,13), (7,14), (13,12), (9,8), (8,0), (0,5), (2,2) ]`

The order is following:

```
[ [(coordinates with largest X)],[(coordinates with largest Y)], [(coordinates with second largest X)], [(coordinates with second largest Y)], [(Third Largest X)], [(Third Largest y)] ... and so on ]
```

I tried to use

```
data.sort(key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=True)
```

first, and then

```
data.sort(key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
```

but it does not work.

What do you think I have to do? 
Please help

Comment: The expected data which you printed is neither ordered using `X` nor `Y`.

Comment: @Prudhvi is right, the expected output seemingly contradicts the rest of your post. I also think that it might not always be possible to sort the tuples like `[[(coordinates with largest X)],[(coordinates with largest Y)],...`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the sort function cannot do what you want. Sorting algorithms assume you are not changing the rules about how to compare elements at every other position.

Here is a O(N^2) altorithm for doing what you want:

```py
data = [ (2,2), (0,5), (8,0), (9,8), (7,14), (13,12), (14,13) ]

coordinate = 0
sorted_data = []
while data:
    largest = max(data, key=lambda x: x[coordinate])
    sorted_data.append(largest)
    data.pop(data.index(largest))
    coordinate = (coordinate + 1) % 2

print(sorted_data)
```

Comment: While this appears to work (even with duplicate tuples) it doesn't seem to be `O(n)`. Increasing n by 10 ( `n -> (12, 120, 1200, 12000))`  I get times increasing by `15x, 58x, 166x`. Which is ok with me as long as it works. ... `data = [(random.randint(1,100000),random.randint(1,100000)) for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Good catch. I meant to say N^2. It is like the simple sorting algorithms, not Nlog(N) sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution that uses Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

data = [ (2,2), (0,5), (8,0), (9,8), (7,14), (13,12), (14,13) ]

d = np.array(data)

d_xy = [np.argsort(d[:, 0])[::-1],
        np.argsort(d[:, 1])[::-1]]

idx_xy = [0, 0] 

alternator = 0

order = []

for k in range(d.shape[0]):

    idx = idx_xy[alternator]

    while (d_xy[alternator][idx] in order):

        idx += 1

    order.append(d_xy[alternator][idx])
    alternator = 1 - alternator
    idx_xy[alternator] = idx

print(d[order])
```

Result:

```
[[14 13]
 [ 7 14]
 [13 12]
 [ 9  8]
 [ 8  0]
 [ 0  5]
 [ 2  2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda x:(max(x),x[0]),reverse=True) 
# [(14, 13), (7, 14), (13, 12), (9, 8), (8, 0), (0, 5), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: Produces incorrect output if runner-up X exceeds larges Y (and other sub-cases). For example: [ (2,2), (0,5), (8,0), (9,8), (7,9), (13,8), (14,7) ]

Answer (score -2):

Not quite sure if I understand what you're trying to do (what happens if a coordinate has both the largest X and the second largest Y?). Looking at your example, it seems to be sorted by `max(X,Y)`, so if that's what you're looking for:

```
data.sort(key=lambda x:max(x),reverse=True)
```

Or maybe something like "sort by `max(X,Y)` but break ties by largest value of X":

```
data.sort(key=lambda x:(max(x),x[0]),reverse=True)
```